# Where is the SQL exception caught in this statement?

Tags: java

```
public void xxx() throws SQLException
{
 Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
 try {
    stmt.executeUpdate("update "+ SYS_TABLE +" set current_day=current_day+ 1 ");
  } finally {
    stmt.close();
 }
}
```

There is a `try` and a `finally` statement but no `catch` in between. Am I reading the question wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here not `catching` but `throws` it. When ever the `SQLException` born will `throws` it directly to upper level.

Read [more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2).

Answer (score 0):

The method `xxx` is declared to throw the `SQLException`. It is not caught in the posted code. Because `SQLException` is a checked exception it must be caught in the caller (or the caller wouldn't compile).

Answer (score 0):

You are not catching the exception. But **throws SQLException** throwing exception to where the method calls from.

if you somewhere calling xxx() method then it will catch the exception. see below.

```
public void yyy()
{
   try { 
        xxx(); 
     } 
   catch(SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e); 
    }
}
```

Hope you can understand from the above code.

Answer (score 0):

The sql exception is not caught in your code, the `try` statement is only used to close the opened `Statement` instance via the `finally` clause. When an exception happens in your `executeUpdate` line, `stmt.close()` is called via the finally clause, and then the exception is propagated to the caller of the `xxx()` method. That means the caller of the `xxx()` method has to decide whether to handle the exception in a `try .. except ..` block, or also propagate it to its caller, and so on.